# Translation not working for custom added roles

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am facing a problem that String translation is only working for Admin and Anonymous users. When I logged in with other users with some custom created roles, then translation is not working.

I provided all the required permissions regarding Locale, String Translation etc. Still not working.

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you translating?

Comment: I am translating by default Search block's "Search" string and also views strings.